# Beer blew up into the airlock. What's next?

Tags: beer, airlock, belgian, blow-off, blow-off-tube

So it happened again. The beer blew out the airlock leaving a water and beer mix behind. The airlock still bubbles as per usual. Now I'm wondering what I should do next.

- Leave it as is
- Replace the airlock with another sanitized airlock and sterile water
- <s>Just replace the water in the airlock</s>
- Replace the airlock with a blow out tube

Any of these the options make as much sense as the next one.

[image: Beer airlock blow out]

I might have over-pitched with a 1.4 pint (0.66L) starter for a 2 gallon Belgian golden strong ale batch.

Comment: You need to leave much more head room in the fermenter,

Comment: Yes, it's been a while since a pitched a yeast starter. It added a little bit of volume that i didn't quite take into account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just clean it up and replace the airlock sanitizer fluid.

If you have a second airlock just prep it and swap. If not just cover with sanitized foil while cleaning.

Comment: Also. Just a good rule of thumb. A blowoff tube is always a great idea. I recommend that simply being the standard instead of airlocks.

Comment: @ÞórgnýrThoroddsen each have their pros and cons. I don't use a blow off system when doing 1g batches.

Comment: I'll have to give a blow off tube a try then.

Comment: @Martin a blow off tube wouldn't prevent this. And should still be cleaned up all the same when it happens. In fact a blow off may even be worse by creating a siphon sucking out a lot of krausen and yeast with it.  Headspace is the only thing to prevent this.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'll will not make the same mistake again; Forgetting to account for the starter.